# Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@vue/server-renderer" from

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a vue3 project created by vite a few months ago, when it was able to debug and release normally, today I am ready to make a little modification, and report an error at runtime,
All vue files are error-reporting:`[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@vue/server-renderer" from "srcApp.vue". Does the file exist?` , I searched globally, and no file referenced `vue/server-renderer`, how to solve this problem?

```
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@vue/server-renderer" from "src\App.vue". Does the file exist?
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: PATH/vue3-element-admin/src/App.vue
  17 |  
  18 |  import { resolveComponent as _resolveComponent, withCtx as _withCtx, createVNode as _createVNode, mergeProps as _mergeProps } from "vue"  
  19 |  import { ssrRenderComponent as _ssrRenderComponent } from "@vue/server-renderer"
     |                                                             ^
  20 |  
  21 |  function _sfc_ssrRender(_ctx, _push, _parent, _attrs, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
      at formatError (PATH\vue3-element-admin\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-0351185a.js:36769:46)
      at TransformContext.error (PATH\vue3-element-admin\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-0351185a.js:36765:19)
      at normalizeUrl (PATH\vue3-element-admin\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-0351185a.js:73694:26)
      at async TransformContext.transform (PATH\vue3-element-admin\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-0351185a.js:73834:57)
      at async Object.transform (PATH\vue3-element-admin\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-0351185a.js:36985:30)
      at async doTransform (PATH\vue3-element-admin\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-0351185a.js:52057:29)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try updating "vite" and "@vitejs/plugin-vue" packages to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the vite, the error is still the same, restored the version of the vite to 2.1.0 to solve the problem.

Comment: Tried that solution with no success. very misleading answer with no link to any doc or example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pharaoh comment.

```
npm install vite@2.1.0
```

solved error.